# Nginx exlude ips from log

Tags: nginx, logging

I have a nginx server install on a Raspian distribution, I want to exclude my local IP from access_log , I try everything I can find on the web and no way to make it work ...

I tried this solution :

```
map $remote_addr $log_ip { "192.168.2.1" 0; "192.168.2.2" 0; default 1; }
```

and then

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy.log main if=$log_ip;
```

but Nginx doesn't start (the status show me that it doesn't recognize `if=$log_ip;`)

I have to explain exactly that I want :

- I have a private website with an auth access hosted on my raspberry (this website is only personnal )
- It runs under Nginx and is protected with Fail2ban which scans the logfile and ban IPs if needed.
- Now I want to optimize the log file to be as lite as possible (I have a module which create a ramdisk and put all logs on it and after writes them on disk this is to save the card from too much write access)
- So I don't need to log my local IP but I want to keep the access_log for Fail2ban to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below rules to `http{}` context of ngnix config.

```
    map $remote_addr $ip_anonym1 {
 default 0.0.0;
 "~(?P<ip>(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+))\.\d+" $ip;
 "~(?P<ip>[^:]+:[^:]+):" $ip;
}

map $remote_addr $ip_anonym2 {
 default .0;
 "~(?P<ip>(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+))\.\d+" .0;
 "~(?P<ip>[^:]+:[^:]+):" ::;
}

map $ip_anonym1$ip_anonym2 $ip_anonymized {
 default 0.0.0.0;
 "~(?P<ip>.*)" $ip;
}

log_format anonymized '$ip_anonymized - $remote_user [$time_local] ' 
   '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent ' 
   '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log anonymized;
```

This wouldn't remove your IP, but can create an anonymous IP instead of the actual one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution I was running an older version of Nginx (1.6.2), I just updated with the latest and it works ...

Nginx 1.7.0+ allows using an if condition in access_log directive itself.